# How to test for secure SMTP mail service on a mail server

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp, network-protocols

I'm working on a project to auto-configure a user's email server settings in Java. I am extracting the mail server from his email address and looking up the MX records of that mail server using the `DirContext` class with `com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory`.

Then I'm opening a `Socket` to each server and testing them using a `HELO` command and checking the responses.

My problem is that this works only when I test it with the unsecure SMTP port 25. How can I use it with the secure port 465?

I tried using Secure Sockets by using

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(mailserver, STANDARD_SMTP_PORT);
```

But all connections get a timeout exception as follows

```
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

Please help.

Further Info: I am not creating a mail client. This is to simplify the mail server settings for an already existing mail client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP-SSL (Port 465) afaik is deprecated, so instead of trying to connect to a ssl socket you'd actually connect "plaintext" on port 25 (or 587 for smtp auth connections), but send **EHLO** instead of *HELO* and see if the server supports STARTTLS which replaces the deprecated SMTP-SSL. after the client sends the STARTTLS command, the connection is encrypted, so, port 25 is not per se "unsecure"

```
telnet alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 173.194.71.26...
Connected to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP i7si4620651lbb.76
EHLO myserver.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS                  <<--------- this is what you're looking for
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
STARTTLS      <<--- client command to actually start encrypting the traffic
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out. But gmail's smtp server is smtp.gmail.com and it uses port 465. So how can it be deprecated?

Comment: many providers still provide SMTP-S for backwards compatibility. gmail offers STARTTLS on smtp.gmail.com port 587 as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you authenticated the program before establishing a connection with the server . Every remote mail server will need to authenticate the machine trying to establish a socket connection . If your using javaMail library for example , you will be given options to add the username and password . You will need to find a workaround while using simple sockets in java